# How to create responsive z-layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a responsive z-layout page using bootstrap. problem is When it come to mobile, the layout is different.

Following is my **HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder" style="width:100%"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 z-first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 z-second"><img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder" style="width:100%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please refer 
[without JS](http://jsfiddle.net/v75htzsr/1/) and [with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/3gjrnLoL/). Is there any way to do without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Bootstrap, but imho, I'm finding the html markup a bit complicated and poor in semantics.

I'm sure it's not perfect, but I would much prefer to work with this markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <img src='YourPicture.png'>
            </img>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <img src='YourPicture.png'>
            </img>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a barebone Style.css file that takes care of the responsive layout part in the manner you wanted for this markup:

```
section
{
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

img
{
    display: block;
}

p
{
    display: block;
}

section:first-child img
{
    float: left;
}

section:nth-child(2) img
{
     float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 768px)
{
    section:first-child img
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }

    section:nth-child(2) img
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

No Javascript :).